# Delete/Update Global Value Set values using Tooling API

Tags: tooling-api, http, global-variables, global-picklist

I'm trying to update or delete values in my Global Value Set.

I succeed insert new values with the code below:

[image]

but when I change SetMethod to DELETE  I get Bad Request with status code 400

is there any way I can delete and update existing values in Global Value Set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot do a delete call**. The easy way to see what you can and cannot do is to look at the Tooling API documentation for [GlobalValueSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_globalvalueset.htm)

[image]

You should be able to update an existing value as long as you GET the specific metadata for one Id. *If you need to do a lot at once, you can also look into* [composite requests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_resources_composite_composite.htm).

```
services/data/v48.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/0Nt7F000000 /**you'll need to get your Id with a query first
```

Once you get the right metadata for that specific value, you can remove all top level attributes except for *full name* and *metadata* so you're just left with the following:

```
{
  "Metadata" : {
    "customValue" : [ {
      "color" : null,
      "default" : false,
      "description" : null,
      "isActive" : null,
      "label" : "Test1",
      "urls" : null,
      "valueName" : "Test1"
    }, {
      "color" : null,
      "default" : false,
      "description" : null,
      "isActive" : null,
      "label" : "Test2",
      "urls" : null,
      "valueName" : "Test2"
    }, {
      "color" : null,
      "default" : false,
      "description" : null,
      "isActive" : null,
      "label" : "Test3",
      "urls" : null,
      "valueName" : "Test3"
    } ],
    "description" : null,
    "masterLabel" : "Test2",
    "sorted" : false,
    "urls" : null
  },
  "FullName" : "Testing"
}
```

You should be able to do another POST to update those values/labels.